# Cant overfit Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a simple encoder-decoder network. The encoder has several layers of conv1d with linear at the end and Relu between them, the decoder is consists of conv1d layers and Relu between them(no batch norm or dropout).
Using this model I try to overfit one example,I work with batch size=1 and always give the same input and same desired output, however no success. The loss indeed goes down until some threshold, but no matter what I do I can't get the loss lower than this bound and the output is useless. I tried more sophisticated encoder/decoder, change hyperparameters, make different preprocessing on my data, but I never can't get the loss lower than that threshold.
Just for the protocol, if I give it as input the desired output(so it will learn the id function) the network works, but that doesn't help me.

I will appreciate any help with it with any idea what might be the problem.

Comment: If your network is deep and you need to use batchnorm, try using batchnorm or any normalization technique and it should work like a magic.

Answer (score 0):

Try more number of epochs, with a lower learning rate.
Try increasing the size of your Dense layers.
Try avoiding any Dropout layers.
These can make the model more vulnerable to overfitting, if this is what you wanted.